# Change of scaling due to a perturbation

Tags: perturbation-theory, non-perturbative, scaling

I am looking for known examples of models where the introduction of a perturbation changes the scaling law of one or more observables.

I would appreciate suggestions relevant to any branch of Physics, especially from Condensed Matter.